# Strong Law of Large Numbers related proof

Tags: random-variable, convergence, law-of-large-numbers

I am trying to prove the following:
[image]

So far I have used Kronecker's Lemma as such:

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\text{Since } \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sigma_i ^2}{B_i ^2} < \infty, \text{ then, } \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{B_n ^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sigma_i ^2 =0
\end{equation}

I am not sure as whether this is correct.

I also know that I have to use the Kolmogorov' Inequality, provided in the question, and the Theorem shown below, however I am not sure how to connect these different arguments such that the question is answered.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]